# print multiple separate histograms in one loop

Tags: python

I want this to print out two histograms (of the first two columns), but this instead stacks the histograms within the same plot. How do I get it to output two separate histograms?

```
dataobj = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
for i in [0,1]:
    a = np.array(dataobj.iloc[:,i])
    plt.hist(a,bins = np.linspace(0,10,11))
```

Even better would be a solution where I can save the plots into an array which I could later call to display them.

Working in Jupyter

Answer (score 3):

```
dataobj = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 12)
for i in range(3):
         a = np.array(dataobj.iloc[:, i])
         axes[i].hist(a, bins=np.linspace(0, 10, 11))
plt.show()
```

u need to use `axes`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `plt.show()` in for loop, no need in subplots and axes. Like this

```
dataobj = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
for i in [0,1]:
    a = np.array(dataobj.iloc[:,i])
    plt.hist(a,bins = np.linspace(0,10,11))
    plt.show()
```